# How to solve this exercise on Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm currently trying to this exercise, but I'm stuck.
My predicate is `Something(Number_Line,List,Islands)`.
The response of this predicate is the structure `islands[Numb_bridge, (Number_line,Column)]`.
Column is the index of the List when the number of bridges isn't 0.
Ex:

```
Something(2, [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9], Islands).    
Islands = [island(5,  (2, 1)), island(9,  (2, 7))].    

Something(4,[0,0,3,1,0,5],Islands).   
Islands = [island(3, (4,3)), island(1, (4,4)), island(5, (4,6))].
```

I'm trying to do in a recursive way, using Count but it's not working, I thought about using Get and Put, so I can storage the number of the column, but I don't know how to use these.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Please explain what all the values mean. For example, why is bridge 9 associated with the values `(2, 7)`?

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

A possible recursive solution is:

```
islands(Line, List, Islands) :-
    islands_loop(List, Line, 1, Islands).

islands_loop([], _, _, []).
islands_loop([X|Xs], Line, Column, Islands) :-
    (   X \= 0                                      % if X is an island
    ->  Islands = [island(X, (Line, Column))|Rest]  % then collect its position
    ;   Islands = Rest   ),                         % else ignore it
    NextColumn is Column + 1,
    islands_loop(Xs, Line, NextColumn, Rest).
```

Examples:

```
?- islands(2, [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9], Islands).
Islands = [island(5,  (2, 1)), island(9,  (2, 7))].

?- islands(4, [0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 5], Islands).
Islands = [island(3,  (4, 3)), island(1,  (4, 4)), island(5,  (4, 6))].
```